# Elements of finite order in congruence subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb Z[i])$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I was told that congruence subgroups of $GL(2,K)$ do not have elements of finite order, where $K$ is an imaginary quaadratic number field. For example, if $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup (or a finite index subgroup thereof) of $GL_2(\mathbb Z[i])$. Is that an easy way to see this? To start, if $A$ is an element of order $N$ and
$$
\phi : \Gamma \to \mathbb C^\times
$$
is a homomorphism, then $1 = \phi(A^N) = \phi(A)^N$, so $\phi(A)$ must be an $N$-th root of unity.

Comment: Isn't $-I_2$ in the congruence subgroup mod $2$?

Comment: And $I_2$ also has finite order. There's a word to mean that the only element of finite order is the unit: "torsion-free".

Comment: Thanks, but what about for larger primes? One tends to avoid small primes that give trouble..

Comment: You can characterize elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])_{tors}$ in term of their characteristic polynomial which must be one of $(x-i^m)(x-i^l)$ or $(x-i^m \zeta_3)(x-i^m \zeta_3^{-1})$ or $(x-i^m \zeta_8^{2l+1})(x-i^m \zeta_8^{5(2l+1)})$

Comment: The right statement is that for all but finitely many primes the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(p)$ in $\Gamma$ are torsion-free. BTW, you should specify that $K$ is a ring of integers of, say, some number field.